# I want to go to another Component when I using onClick()

Tags: reactjs, onclick, components

My project is a bit trouble when I tried to add Component on a function.

When I click on the text:

```
<td
                                                className='text-primary'
                                                style={{
                                                    maxHeight: '21px',
                                                    width: '8%',
                                                    maxWidth: '300px'
                                                }}
                                                onClick={(event) => {onEditLangClicked(event,item)}}
                                            >
                                                {item.language_name}
                                            </td>
```

it will go to onEditLangClicked:

```
function onEditLangClicked(event,lang){
        setEditMode(true);
        setLang(lang);
        <ModalAddNgonNgu />
        console.log/(lang);
    }
```

And I should go to  Component:

```
const ModalAddNgonNgu = (props) => {
    //Kind of stuff
    return (
        <>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModalAddNgonNgu" style={{ fontSize: '14px' }}>
                Thêm
            </button>
            


//Just some HTML
                 
}

export default ModalAddNgonNgu;
```

So what should I change in onEditLangChecked(event,lang)? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create state to indicate when you did mount your component like

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
```

Changing the state you change the component to display. For example

```
visible ? <Component1 />: <Component2 />
```